# Can't Connect Android Device to PC on Windows 8

Tags: android, windows-8

I've tried everything, when I run 'adb devices' on my new HP Envy Windows 8 laptop I get a blank 'list of devices attached'.  I've reinstalled the USB driver for the phone (Samsung Galaxy s3), I've set it to developer settings. The only clue as to what is wrong is when I performed troubleshooting on the hardware and devices control panel it said I have USB 3.0 ports and a USB 2.0 device.  Though I read that the ports would be backwards compatible.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `adb connect` ?

Comment: check your device in device in this path : 
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers

Comment: I get unable to connect to 192.168.2.xx

Comment: @mohammed device is SCH-I535

Comment: I get an explicit error message saying that SCH-I535 will not work with USB 3.0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [android.se]

Answer (score 13):

2014-April:  I agree this is an issue with Windows 8 / 8.1 and this approach was only successful by happenstance.

On my Win8.1 system, even with Samsung's official driver installed (see link below), my SGH-I727 Galaxy SII Skyrocket would not connect over USB - neither with MTP nor PTP enabled on the device under Settings > Storage > [press menu] > USB Computer Connection.

I ended up doing the following, while the phone was **untethered**, and after installing the Samsung driver:

1. Open an elevated CMD prompt, if logged in as a non-admin
2. Type: set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=yes [press enter]
3. Launch DEVMGMT.MSC
4. Clicked VIEW > enabled SHOW HIDDEN DEVICES
5. Expand Universal Serial Bus controllers
6. Right-click uninstall all entities that appeared in gray [gray = *not* present]
7. Expand System Devices and repeat removal of non-present devices.
   [NO REBOOT WAS REQUIRED at this point]
8. Plugged the phone into a standard USB port - still unresolved
9. Plugged the phone into a USB 3.0 port - device was recognized and installed itself

There is now an entry under **Universal Serial Bus controllers** named "SAMSUNG Mobile USB Composite Device". The driver tab for that entity is dated 02-Jan-2014 with version 2.11.7.0 from "SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd."  Note this version is different than the one downloaded directly from Samsung (see link below) which is 1.5.14.0.

There are now also two new entries under **Portable Devices**: "MTP USB Device" which is presently gray despite the device being currently connected, and "SAMSUNG-SGH-I727".

**Windows Explorer** now shows a device named "SAMSUNG-SGH-I727" and, when opened, shows both "Internal Storage" as well as "SD Card" directories.

**ALSO NOTE** that the phone has to **REMAIN UNLOCKED**, in order for Windows Explorer to provide access to the aforementioned directories.  Most smartphones will block access to these directories, when the phone's interface is locked due to your security preferences. In other words, ensure you swipe or enter your passcode and remain seeing your phone's main screen, while trying to view its directories via tether.

Samsung Driver [version 1.5.14.0]:
[www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I727MSAATT](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I727MSAATT)

Comment: Following steps 1-7 fixed my problem. Windows 8.1 saw my phone when I plugged it in (step 8). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you mounting the device as a camera?

In other words, head over to `Settings` > `Storage` > `"Usb computer connection"` (via the ActionBar) > `Camera (PTP)`.

Comment: I have it connected as a camera.  I also tried it connected as a media device.

Comment: Which drivers did you install?

Comment: Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Samsung drivers are installed. Power off your phone. Power on the phone in Download mode. (Volume Down + Home + Power) Press Volume Up to continue. Once it's in Download mode, plug it into your computer. Windows should now discover it and load the driver. Once this is complete, unplug the phone from the computer, and pull the battery out of the phone to get out of Download mode. Replace the battery, and power on the phone like normal. It should connect to the computer properly. 
this from this thread 
http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/286104-s3-wont-connect-via-usb-my-computer.html

the problems will be related to the driver i face problems like this with my android device connecting to my pc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (samsung note 3, hp win 8.1).  When plugged in, the phone would constantly connect and disconnect.  I tried 3 things - delete the whole driver from device manager (did nothing), swap from USB 2.0 port to usb 3.0 port (may have been part of getting it working) and changing one drive settings.

One drive has a setting to sync data across all devices.  It appears that windows trying to grab sensitive data from the phone was causing it to reset the connection.  When I turned that off I got a stable basic connection.

I may be the only one, but I am creeped out that MS takes every opportunity to behave as spyware.

Good luck, I hope that helps